# Send command to WPF application using WindowsDriver

Tags: c#, wpf, appium

I trying to writer auto test with WindowsDriver and face to some limitations of ui controls. Maybe there is way to interact with my wpf app by calling some kind of commands through WindowsDriver? F.e. send message to window of my test app.